# Hibernate automatic save after Transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

This is my hibernate relationship

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = false)
@XmlElement
@JsonIgnore
@Getter
@Setter
private List<A> aList = new ArrayList<>();



@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
@XmlTransient
@Getter
@Setter
private B b;
```

So would be like I call method x, there I´m get from database entity B then I set new aList with all A with id null, into B and then I return B in the method but I´m not saving B in any moment. When I see the value of the aList inside B this A of the aList already have ids!!!, so in some point the B is save in database and aList is done on cascade. 
The thing is that I´m calling this method inside @Service class from my Controller, so I´m thinking that because the transaction is finish, Hibernate detect a change into the B and decide to persist the changes. The question would be, how avoid that behavior!!!

Answer (score 0):

Object in session cache will be synchronized with database on `Session.flush()`, including relations as you are using `CascadeType.ALL`.

If you want to avoid the synchronization on some object, you can use the `Session.evict(someObject)` method before the transaction commit.

Comment: I´m adding the entity as evict into the session, but still is persisting the changes. Could be because the entity that I´m doing evict is an instance that belong to another instance by foreing key.

Comment: I achieve to remove the class B from the session but now I´m having this Hibernate exception org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist

Comment: Seems like it is referenced by another transitive relation. You could clone the B instance before changing it or try to evict upstream in the object graph  (if it makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I forgot to say that I´m using Spring, so finally I add the     @Transactional(readOnly=true) into my method instead in the service class level.

Comment: Don't trust on readOnly tags, see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts1/